# Add assert info to symfony command line generations of CRUD entities

Tags: symfony, entity, assertions

Is it possible to add Assert requirements to the command line when generating an entity? In other words when I run "../app/console doctrine:generate:entity ...", how can I add information such that the entity has the type of assertions shown here:

```
/**
 * 
 * @var string $PID
 * @ORM\Column(name="PID", type="string", length=50)
 * 
 * 
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *   pattern="/^(\d{7,7}[Aa])$|^(\d{8,8})$/",
 *   message="Format Must Be 8 digets Or 7 Digits Followed By 'A'"
 * )
 */
private $PID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the validation component:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

Simply use it to validate the entity when it's created:

```
$validator = $this->get('validator'); // Or wherever you can get services from
$errors    = $validator->validate($entity);

if (count($errors) > 0) {
    // Handle errors here...
} else {
    // Success!
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for the syntax - if it exists - that will do that from the Symfony command line.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean now. You want to automatically generate the assertions when the entity is generated? There isn't any built in functionality for that. The command you run to generate entities is built in thanks to Doctrine, but the validation component is completely separate from Doctrine. If you want this kind of behaviour, you may be able to add your own command to do this, but it'd not be easy I'd be willing to bet. The thing is, your assertions are there for things like forms and the like, so it would be extremely difficult to automatically generate that.

Comment: Thank you Seer.  That's what I was beginning to suspect.